# Css- Background Image get cropped top and bottom

Tags: html, css

Size of the image is 1274 x 793. i want it as my background image. but when add it on css, it get cropped top and bottom. i want it to show full size on my page without stretching it on the page.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
/*Banner Section*/

#banner {
    height: 100%;
    background: url('/wonderwoman.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: @talha, why do you keep editing questions and adding spaces in the code? This is the second question I've seen you do this to. What you do makes the code invalid. CSS won't read `100 %` it will only read `100%`

Comment: i didn't understand what you said actually. this is my first question here.

Comment: @Ihazkode, my bad, the beautifier tool was adding spaces and making the code invalid. Thanks for pointing this out. All I try to do is to beautify/format/indent the code to make it easier to read (some people post with horrible formatting). OP's code was actually alright except for last bracket. Will be careful next time! Thanks again.

Comment: thank you..i don't know much about this platform actually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `background-size:contain;` 
or
you can partially avoid distortion of the image aspect ratio by constraining either image minimum dimension (e.g.) `min-height: 700px;`

Comment: hey it worked now but there are little empty space above. i need to fix this. can you help?

Comment: Thank you so much man..........................i also solved that problem of empty space by background-position: center top;

Comment: Next time add related html codes as well. Because these styles can override with other styles on the page.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this as well

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:#000;">
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
<img src="wonderwoman.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"  align="center"> 
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i also have to add content on the image.. and i can't do like this. do you have any idea why it's getting cropped?

Comment: share your image

Answer (score 0):

add

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: This stretches the image. it doesn't give me full height

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "background-position: center center;" part.

Comment: As you mentioned in main answer comment "background-position: center top;". It was the one of issues. I actually recreated above issue with given tags but it fixed with removing this. Next time add related html codes as well. Because these styles can override with other styles on the page.